# Node how to manage user roles i want to redirect user to admin or coach dashbord when (is_admin & is_coach) is true in user table? login code is below

Tags: mysql, reactjs, sequelize-cli

Node how to manage user roles? I want to redirect user to admin or coach dashboard when (is_admin & is_coach) is true in user table? login code is below?

I had used Nodejs for Backend and Reactjs for Frontend and for database i had used Mysql

(here is my signin code )

```js
exports.signIn = (req, res) => {
  const reqData = req.body;
  checkAccountExistence(reqData)
    .then((userDetails) => {
      if (userDetails.length > 0) {
        checkUserActivation(userDetails[0])
          .then((activeUser) => {
            if (activeUser.length == 1) {
              bcrypt.compare(
                reqData.password.toString(),
                userDetails[0].password,
                (error, response) => {
                  if (response) {
                    var token = jwt.sign(
                      { id: userDetails[0].id },
                      config.secret,
                      {
                        expiresIn: 86400,
                      }
                    );
                    res.cookie("userToken", token, { maxAge: 86400000 });
                    res.send({ loginSuccess: true });
                  } else {
                    res.send({ invalidMessage: "Invalid Email or Password" });
                  }
                }
              );
            } else {
              const emailData = userDetails[0];
              const randnum = Math.random().toString(25).substring(2, 20);
              updateActivationCode(userDetails[0], randnum)
                .then((response) => {
                  if (response == 1) {
                    emailData.randnum = randnum;
                    emailData.firstname = emailData.first_name;
                    emailData.template = "accountVerification.ejs";
                    generateEmail(emailData)
                      .then((html) => {
                        emailData.html = html;
                        const emailOptions = {
                          from: '"Tester" testmail@zoho.com',
                          to: emailData.email,
                          subject: "Account verification",
                          html: emailData.html,
                        };
                        sendMail(emailOptions);
                        res.send({
                          verifyMessage:
                            "Please check your mail to verify your account first",
                        });
                      })
                      .catch((error) => {
                        res.send(error);
                      });
                  }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.log(error);
                });
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      } else {
        res.send({ invalidMessage: "Invalid Email or Password" });
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(422).send({
        error: error.errors.map((err) => {
          return {
            attribute: err.path,
            type: err.type,
            message: err.message,
          };
        }),
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: How do you check `is_admin` & `is_coach` is true?

Comment: it is mentioned in database! is_admin can be true or false if true then user must reach admin dashboard and similar should happen to coach

Comment: Well, yes.. but I don't see any query to look for it in your code above.

Comment: i have add this function now

Comment: for now it is reddirecting user to user dashboard

Comment: i have to restrict user which is student as true in db to reach admin or coach dashboard

Comment: just for curios could you just read about [`callback function hell`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-callback-hell-in-node-js/)

Comment: when user us logging in and puts the data in the fields on frontend it gets stored in reqData then account existance is checked in a separate function